# How to export valiables value to text file when run gdb in os ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans, gdb, cygwin

I have a c ++ program with Netbeans IDE and cygwin. I want to run the program, then export all values of all variables to text file.

Answer (score 0):

Use command **dump** to copy the data to destination file

Ex : dump [format] value filename expr

for detail about copying to file check the [link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html)

Comment: can you give me a specific example?